# Problemas al clonar proyecto Laravel Voyager

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy apoyando en un proyecto desarrollado con laravel-voyager y me pasa que al clonar el repositorio, no me trae todos los menus ni tablas que tiene mi colega en master.

Acá una imagen. Todo lo marcado en rojo, aparecía en el menu.
Utilicé el paquete migration generator al menos para rescatar las tablas, per queda nuevamente por hacer el bread y crear los menus.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisando claro, el voyager está en vendor, carpeta que no se sube al git.
Alguien que haya hecho esto antes'? que configuración hay que hacer para pasar todo lo de voyager para subirlo a git (Menus,  Breads, etc).?. Ya que tendré el mismo problema cuanto tenga que hacer push a lo que yo haga.

La versión de laravel es 5.7
Saludos y gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Por lo general no se recomienda mover ninguna de las carpetas que se encuentren en vendor ya que son las dependencias que se instalan por defecto cuando instalas con composer o las que vienen por defecto cuando instalas laravel.
Si ese tu caso quieres subir la carpetas que se encuentran en vendor tienes que entrar al archivo .gitignore y introducir la carpeta que quieres subir sin importar que con `!/vendor/directory/` para que git pueda subir los cambios de dicha carpeta, posterior genera el commit para subir dicha carpeta.

Comment: finalmente, tambien me seguí por las recomendaciones y no toqué nada en vendor.
Exporté los inserts de la base de datos an un sql. y estos traen la configuracion de menus. Bueno, con esto me sirve para avanzar. 
Gracias por tu comentario @javiershaka

Comment: Se me olvido comentar que hay un comando que es `php artisan vendor:publish` que sirve de importar de manera automatica la cosas que tienes en la carpeta vendor (dependiendo la dependencia que estes usando) a tu proyecto en general, como vistas, controladores etc.